# Silverstripe Sessions or URL Parameters

Tags: session, silverstripe

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a value from my .ss page to my controller for a custom search filter that I've built.  The idea is you click on this image or a form button and then the page will set a session variable and refresh itself.  Upon page load the page loads different information depending on what it reads in the session variable.  I can accomplish the same thing with URL Parameters but there are no examples online that I could find that would show me how to do this.

Basically I have this as my php:

```
class ArticleHolder_Controller extends Page_Controller {
public function ValidateType(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['mySearchTag']) && !empty($_SESSION['mySearchTag'])) {
        $tag = $_SESSION['mySearchTag'];
    }
    else{
        $tag='News';
    }

    $filter = $this::get()->filter('Filters:PartialMatch', $tag)->First();
    if ($filter == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['mySearchTag']=$tag;
        return $this->PaginatedPages();
    }
}
public function PaginatedPages(){
    $paginatedItems = new PaginatedList($this->filterArticles($_SESSION['mySearchTag']), $this->request);
    $paginatedItems->setPageLength(3);
    return $paginatedItems;
}
public function filterArticles($tag){
    return ArticlePage::get()->filter('category:PartialMatch', $tag)->sort('Date DESC');
}
```

}

my .ss looks like this:

```
<% if ValidateType() %>
        <ul>
            <% loop $PaginatedPages %>
                <li>
                    <div class="article">
                        <h2><a href="$Link" title="Read more on &quot;{$Title}&quot;">$Title</a></h2>
                        <h3>$Date</h3>
                        <img class="indent" src="$Photo.link" alt="image"/>
                        <p class="indent">$Teaser</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <% end_loop %>
        </ul>
        <% include Pagination %>
    <% else %>
        <p>SORRY NO RESULTS WERE FOUND</p>
    <% end_if %>
```

This code works as is.  What I cannot figure out how to now add a clickable button on .ss page that will reload the page and set a session variable value.

If I can achieve this with url parameters then that can work too, I just need to know how to set them in the .ss page and how to retrieve them in the php.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `SetFilter` function that will take the URL parameter ID and set it to your session variable:

```
public function SetFilter() {

    if($this->request->param('ID')) {
        $_SESSION['mySearchTag'] = $this->request->param('ID');
    }

    return array();
}
```

Make sure your `SetFilter` function is added to the `$allowed_actions` of your controller:

```
static $allowed_actions = array (
    'SetFilter'
);
```

This function is called by your page link followed by `/SetFilter/[your-filter]`.

In your template you would create a link to create this filter like so:

```
<a href="{$Link}SetFilter/example" title="Filter articles by example">Filter articles by example</a>
```